# Need help solving this inequality involving factorial

Tags: inequality, factorial

I really have no idea how to solve this inequality, I would be happy with just a hint on how to solve it :)

$$\frac{e^{0.5}0.5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \le 10^{-6}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most important thing to notice is that when $n$ increases, the expression on the left decreases. Therefore all you need to do is find the smallest value of $n$ for which the inequality is true - according to Marcelo Fornet's answer, this is $n = 7$ - and then the set of solutions consists of all values of $n$ greater than or equal to this initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest you to binary search the answer, but after computing the first 11 values I've got this:

- $f(0) = 0.8243606353500641$
- $f(1) = 0.20609015883751602$
- $f(2) = 0.03434835980625267$
- $f(3) = 0.004293544975781584$
- $f(4) = 0.0004293544975781584$
- $f(5) = 3.577954146484653\cdot10^{-05}$
- $f(6) = 2.5556815332033237\cdot10^{-06}$
- $f(7) = 1.5973009582520773\cdot10^{-07}$
- $f(8) = 8.87389421251154\cdot10^{-09}$
- $f(9) = 4.4369471062557704\cdot10^{-10}$
- $f(10) = 2.0167941392071684\cdot10^{-11}$

The value of n that suits you is 7.